# HighStock - padding

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i need padding between yaxis and first point of the line using zoom. I need get something like this http://jsfiddle.net/SineDie/xajHE/ with a HighStock library.

An example with HighChart (without zoom)

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        marginLeft: 30
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        tickInterval: 1,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 2
    },
    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        tickWidth: 1,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 2,
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        tickInterval: 50,
        gridLineWidth: 0
        /*,offset:-26*/
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [100, 125, 150, 125, 90]
    },{
        data: [100, 80, 90, 80, 70]
    },{
        data: [100, 90, 80, 60, 180]
    }]
});
```

});